# custom auto increment on payment slip

Tags: php, mysql

We are building a table (payment_slip) with following structure...

```
+------+------+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| id   |      | recipt_code | prodcuct    | user     | dnt                 |
+------+------+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| 4    |      | 2011/1      | ABC         | tester   | 2011-02-17 23:36:12 |
+------+------+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
```

And we want to add field recipt_code by using auto increment as it should be unique and by proper series like 2011/1 2011/2 2011/3 2011/4, so what is the best way to achieve this? please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2:

Try this code. New 'id' generation is incapsulated in a function `generate_recipt_code`
, so you could call this function from your INSERT statement directly, in the script or in the php.

```
CREATE TABLE payment_slip(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  recipt_code VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  prodcuct VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  user VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  dnt DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION generate_recipt_code()
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_recipt_code VARCHAR(255);

  SET @date = NOW();
  SET @year = IF(MONTH(@date) < 4, YEAR(@date) - 1, YEAR(@date));
  SELECT
    COALESCE(
    CONCAT(@year, '/', MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(recipt_code, '/', -1) * 1) + 1),
    CONCAT(@year, '/1')
    )
  INTO
    new_recipt_code
  FROM
    payment_slip
  WHERE
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(recipt_code, '/', 1) = @year;

  RETURN new_recipt_code;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES(NULL, generate_recipt_code(), 'ABC', 'tester', '2011-02-17 23:36:12');
```

PHP code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host_name', 'user_name', 'user_password', 'db_name', '3306');

$prodcuct = 'product1';
$user = 'user1';
$dnt = '2011-04-01 12:00:00';

$sql="INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES(NULL, generate_recipt_code(), '$prodcuct', '$user', '$dnt')";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: @Devart is there any simpler method like get maxval()/lastinsertid from myvalue and post back with +1 for new entry.

Comment: thanks, wow you have got the point, but our financial year starts from april 1 of each year, so is there any way to reset it from 1 again on each april 1. and how would it take value, for inserting new row, it would be great if you could add insert query as well. thanks for great.

Comment: do you know php, if yes, so how to add new recipt no. using php, would i need to use php for creating new and unique receipt no. please help, thanks.

Comment: so i would need these fields now.. id(AUTOINC & Primary) | recipt_no(Unique) | product | user | dnt , i am confused about how to insert value into recipt_no... using php or direct by mysql insert query. hope you got my point, thanks for yours best help.

Comment: I changed my answer. Example inserts new row and generates new id automatically. Hope this what you want ;)

Comment: thanks, even contact me if you can. want to discuss some work.

Comment: can we do this insert query in mysqli prepared statement?

Comment: I'm not php expert; but something can. I have added php-code that inserts new row into table (see answer).

Comment: thanks for great support, i want to keep in touch with you, how can we? As i may need more sql help and i am ready to pay. thanks.

Comment: waiting for your reply over mail, and please let me know how to delete any function using phpmyadmin.

Comment: hello, can you answer this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648597/mysql-inner-join

Comment: @Devart creating 2011/10 for 11th entry instead of 2011/11

Comment: @seoppc There was a problem with MAX functoin, for strings it returns '9' for values '9' and '10'; so there should be nembers. This can be fixed adding '* 1' to cast this value to string - 'MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(recipt_code, '/', -1) * 1)'. Answer is modified. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot have 2 columns with same name (`id` and `id`). You can achieve desired results by using BEFORE triggers, `BEFORE INSERT` in particular:

```
DELIMITER $$$
CREATE TRIGGER YourTableBeforeINsert BEFORE INSERT ON YourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN      
   DECLARE prev_num UNSIGNED INT;
    // calculate your new_code
    SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(receipt_code,'_',-1) AS UNSIGNED)) INTO prev_num 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YEAR(dnt) = YEAR(new.dnt);
    IF (prev_num IS NULL) THEN
      SET prev_num = 1;
    ELSE 
      SET prev_num = prev_num+1;
    END IF;
    SET new.receipt_code = CONCAT(YEAR(new.dnt),'_',prev_num); 
END
$$$
```

**UPDATE**
  I added a code that generates a new receipt number (Year+'_'+Number). I believe it should work, though I didn't test it.

Comment: I believe I already posted query. I'm not sure how you want to calculate a code value for new row, whether it should be just year + id ('2011_1','2011_2', '2012_3', etc) or you want a new sequence for each year ('2011_1', '2011_2', '2012_1', '2012_2', etc)?

Comment: @a1ex07 is there any simpler method like get maxval()/lastinsertid from myvalue and post back with +1 for new entry.

Comment: You can create a new column to and increment its value for each year. Auto-increment column increments every time you insert a new row, so it will work for the first year.

Comment: how to keep order of auto increment rows, for example in my table i see id as 1,2,3,4,8,12,44 , how can we keep those in order? is there any fix?

Comment: You have a gap between ids if you remove records or if you rollback transaction that previously inserted a record into the table (or if you manually edit/insert autoincrement field). Keeping them in order involves changing value of primary key which is always not a good idea.

Comment: so i should create another column with auto increment on it and it would add +1 at each new row, and then CONCAT with it prefix while taking output. what do you say? but there is a problem i want to reset it from 0 again on each financial year(April) so it can have duplicate entries in that column, only that's by i thought prefixing year with it, ok if increment is activated on column how would it create another row in case of 2011/1 + 1

Comment: You cannot have 2 auto_increment columns in one table.

Comment: so would it be good by adding +1 after getting MAX(val) from db, or any other simpler way, please help.

Comment: ok tell me something for example if we have 3 rows 2011/1, 2011/2, 2011/3 so what MAX(reciptcode) would return and even if we add 2011/1 +1, what would it return. thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `id` column (I assume this is already auto incremented) the receipt code like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dnt, '%Y'), '/', id) AS recipt_code
FROM `table_name`
```

This is assuming of course that the `2011` in your receipt codes is the year of the transaction (`dnt` column).

Comment: thanks great and how will i add next recipt number after 2011/1

Comment: If you want that /# to reset at the beginning of the year, this won't work. You'll end up with the last receipt in 2000 being 2000/456 and the first of 2001 being 2001/457. But simply concatenating the two is definitely the easiest way to build the compound ID.

Comment: is there any way or function to reset(start with Y/1) it by each financial year(1 apr year)?

Comment: and please post code for adding recipt_code to mysql using php or provide just mysql query.

Comment: even you have used id for CONCAT but you know we can't id by serial, it would break its series. So thats by i have used recipt_code as different field(recipt_code) to manually insert code.

Comment: @Marc B is of course correct and I thought that would be implied in my answer, but I guess I should really have pointed that out. @seoppc I think @Sander Marechal's answer is the only way forward for you if you must have the series begin again in the new year. My answer is definitely simpler and if the business decision could be changed to accommodate it it would be my choice for sure.

Comment: @Treffynnon is there any simpler method like get maxval()/lastinsertid from myvalue and post back with +1 for new entry.

Comment: @seoppc "can you even give me INSERT query for your code?". Seriously what is the magic word? Please perhaps? Mate, I have given you the code and the caveats it is not difficult for you to figure out an insert statement based upon my code.

Answer (score 0):

A rather nasty way would be to use a `LOCK TABLE`, then generate a new code on the PHP side, insert your new record and then unlock the tables again. It's nasty, clunky and will get you into concurrency trouble if you do it too often, but it works.

Sample code (untested):

```
$db->sql('LOCK TABLE payment_slip WRITE');
$row = $db->sql('SELECT recipt_code FROM payment_slip ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(recipt_code, 5), UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0,1');
$next_num = intval(substr($row['recipt_code'], 5)) + 1;
$next_code = date('Y') . '/' . $next_num;
$db->sql('INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES (?, ?, ...)', array(...));
$db->sql('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Alternatively, you can store the highest code in a separate table. This has two advantages. First, you don't need to sort a whole bunch of rows to find the highest value. Second, it will keep on working even when you delete rows (like, the row with the highest code value). Locks are still required to make it atomic. This example assumes there's a simple key->value table called `config`.

```
$db->sql('LOCK TABLE payment_slip WRITE, config WRITE');
$row = $db->sql('SELECT value FROM config WHERE key = ?', 'max_recipt_code');
$next_num = intval(substr($row['value'], 5)) + 1;
$next_code = date('Y') . '/' . $next_num;
$db->sql('UPDATE config SET value = ? WHERE key = ?', $next_code, 'max_recipt_code');
$db->sql('INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES (?, ?, ...)', array(...));
$db->sql('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Comment: is there any simpler method like get maxval()/lastinsertid from myvalue and post back with +1 for new entry.

Comment: No, not really. You could do the whole insert in one go using `INSERT ... SELECT` but that will be even scarier than my answer. It's either this, a trigger like alex07 suggest, or you need to build your own source of recipt_codes (which you can then simply assign in PHP). The trick is that such a source *must* be truly atomic. If two processes as for a new code at the *exact* same time, the source must return two sequential numbers. In my answer, this is done by using a `LOCK` to make the two request sequential.

Comment: is there any solution to keep series on id, for example we have row set of id 1,2,3 (we deleted 4) so it takes 5 after 3, so is there any solution to make it in order?

Comment: Yes, but you need an extra table and you still need all the locks. See my updated answer.

Comment: so would i have to create config table and where to put this code.