# mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am using following query to get report from different table of my database, check following...

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, c.name AS course_name,
s.open_bal AS open_balance, sum(i.amount) AS gross_fee,
sum(i.discount) AS discount, sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount) AS net_payable,
SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS net_recieved,
(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount)) - SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS balance_due
FROM students s
INNER JOIN courses c on c.id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN invoices i on i.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN recipts r on r.student_id = s.id;
```

Invoices

```
| id | student_id | amount   | discount |  dnt        | 
+----+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 2  | 22         | 35000    | 0        |  2011/01/01 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Not getting correct value from gross_fee and net_payable.

thanks.

Comment: can you alter my code with yours please?

Comment: try changing the `INNER` to `LEFT` join and share the result

Comment: @Teneff check question again please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `SUM`s in the select I suppose that `GROUP BY s.id` should do the trick. Anyway a `GROUP BY` seems to be missing :)

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, c.name AS course_name,
s.open_bal AS open_balance,
SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS net_recieved,
 (sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount)) - SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS balance_due
FROM students s
INNER JOIN courses c on c.id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN invoices i on i.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN recipts r on r.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

EDIT

Separate query allowing to retrieve **gross_fee** and **net_payable** for all invoices

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS gross_fee,
  sum(discount) AS discount,
  sum(amount) - sum(discount) AS net_payable,
FROM invoices;
```

Comment: thanks for your answers and right i was missing GROUP By, can you even check the code once again to see if i am doing any mistake or i can optimize this code.

Comment: @Frosty Z its even giving me wrong value of gross_fee and net_payable.

Comment: Looks Ok for me. Quite a lot of SUMs however. If you face perf problems with `GROUP BY`, here are some interesting reads: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: Concerning the "wrong values", please edit your question and explain precisely what you are expecting for those values (e.g. gross_fee per student or per course?)

Comment: I need gross fee per student and i think you have got my calculation from given code. check my invoice table in question

Comment: If all the calculated values are "per student", you should do `GROUP BY s.id` like ToonMariner suggested. Edited my answer.

Comment: i did like that, see invoice table, its returning gross_fee as 70000 instead of 35000 as per my table, i want to do the total of all pending invoices.

Comment: So I guess that you should have two separate queries then - one to retrieve pending invoices "overall statistics" - one to retrieve data "per student" ?

Comment: can't we do this in 1 query as all other fields are returning correct value except gross_fee and net_payable

Comment: Would be possible (I guess by adding subqueries into SELECT) but certainly not performance-wise.

Comment: can you update code with this, i am really stuck with it. thanks.

Comment: and how should i merge or link both queries?

Comment: You can use MySQL user defined variables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html
Something like `SELECT @gross_fee := sum(amount), etc.` and then reuse them in your second query.

Answer (score 0):

Have both student records got a value for s.course_id?

You've got an Inner Join from students to courses...

INNER JOIN courses c on c.id = s.course_id

If s.course_id is null in one of the student records, the query will only return one row.